# Limit entry to just one category?

Tags: categories, control-panel, ee3

Is it possible to limit an entry to just one category in the EE3 CP?
Seems that the only option is to have checkboxes so an entry can be signed to multiple categories.

Is there no way to have it set as a bulleted list? Im sure this was the case with EE2.

Very frustrating that such simple functionality is missing from EE3.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used categories in production but I know it's possible to create a category group with just one category.

Then, you could assign this single category as **default category** for a channel in Channel Manager -> Channel Settings (gear icon)  -> Defaults: Category.

Does that help?

I'm not exactly sure what your requirements are. What do you mean with a bulleted list?